# Are there any wallets that support the FA 1.x token standard yet?

Tags: wallets

As StakerDAO moves towards mainnet launch, we are looking for a wallet partner that will enable the display of our token data.  The STKR token is built on the FA 1.2 standard.  Do any wallets support this yet?

Answer (score 3):

[AirGap](https://airgap.it) has implemented the FA 1.2 standard for a token. This is not yet released to the public and scheduled for a security audit.

Best would be to have a chat with Pascal on the Tezos Slack or on [Telegram](https://t.me/AirGap).

Answer (score 2):

Alex from TzStats. We're working on supporting indexing and display of FA1.2 right now. I'm happy to collaborate to get this feature working ASAP. Please get in touch on our Discord server https://discord.gg/D5e98Hw

As base layer for decoding FA1.2 and other contract data we'll be using our bigmap index and storage decode features described [here](https://tzstats.com/docs/api/index.html#bigmaps).